# Unix: Remove date from filename using sed without modifying existing one

Tags: bash, shell, date, unix, sed

I have a legacy code which transmits the file only if it has date within the command. But client transmission doesnt want date to be appended to filename. legacy code cannot be modified since many other transmision depends on it. So my requirement is i want to have date parameter in the command but again the same has to be removed using a single command.

Condition in legacy code:

```
 grep '\`date' $COMMAND
```

Note: COMMAND will contain the complete command defined below and not the filename (not CMD output).

So ideally my command should have `date added. I added a command like this below.

```
CMD=`echo prefix_filename.txt | sed 's/^prefix_//'`_`date +%m%d%Y`
```

The above command is used to remove prefix_ and send filename. Here i get output as filename.txt_09232016. Since legacy code logic only checks if command has `date in it, i added it. Is there a way to remove the date again in the same command so that my output will be filename.txt

Current output:

```
filename.txt_09232016
```

Expected output:

```
 filename.txt
```

Comment: I tried to add `#date but legacy code checks for `date and it doesnt satisy. Am i doing something wrong?

Comment: I added that in my recent update. It is being checked in legacy code if my CMD string has `date and if true it does transmission. This is what it is, HASCMD=`grep '\`date' $CMD`

Comment: Are you really tied to `sed` here? Bash can do this for you natively without having to start a pair of separate processes and a pipe.

Comment: That's a really ugly thing to do in the legacy code. Any chance you could copy the legacy code, modify it, and use it just for your process?

Comment: CMD command is at my hands. only the legacy cant be modified. I can use other option too, its just that i need to have date in that command to satisfy legacy code

Comment: A.L.Flanagan, I agree to that. I never expected that, i executed command separately and was fine without date. but never expected this shocker and which cannot be modified now. I dont have the option you said because i have to incorporate using same logic :(

Comment: Legacy command `grep '\`date' $CMD` is assuming `$CMD` is a filename

Answer (score 3):

Get the file name before date part:

```
echo 'filename.txt_09232016' | grep -o '^.*\.txt'
```

Or remove date from the end of the file:

```
echo 'filename.txt_09232016' | sed 's/_[0-9]\+$//'
```

Comment: Thanks let me try this.

Comment: Is there a way, i can incorporate this in my current CMD statement itself? so output gets assigned to CMD

Comment: current_filename_with_date=...
    filename=$(echo "$current_filename_with_date" | sed 's/_[0-9]\+$//')

Comment: Thanks :) But is it quite possible to have this change in the same command where CMD gets assigned instead of going to a new line and removing date timestamp again. Because the command is stored in a text file and script reads from them. Whatever is inside CMD= <> is read from a text file

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of things you can do to improve/simplify your code. The main thing is that bash have very nice built-in string manipulation. Another is that you should probably use `$(...)` instead of `` `...` `` notation:

```
CMD=`echo prefix_filename.txt | sed 's/^prefix_//'`_`date +%m%d%Y`
```

Can be replaced with

```bash
ORIG=prefix_filename.txt
CMD=${ORIG#prefix_}_$(date +%m%d%Y)
```

Continuing,

```
echo $CMD
NODATE=${CMD%_*}
echo $NODATE
```

This prints

```
filename.txt_09232016
filename.txt
```

The construct [`${var#pattern}`](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/parameter-substitution.html#PSOREX2) removes the shortest occurrence of `pattern` from the start of your variable: in this case, `prefix_`. Similarly, the construct [`${var%pattern}`](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/parameter-substitution.html#PCTPATREF) removes the shortest occurrence of `pattern` from the end of your string: in this case `_*`.

In the first case, you could have used `${var##pattern}` since `prefix_` is a fixed string. However, in the second case you could not use `${var%%pattern}`, since you want to make sure you only truncate starting at the last underscore, not the first one and the date is specified as a dynamic pattern.

Just as an FYI, the links point to [www.tldp.org](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/Bash-Beginners-Guide.html), which has the best Bash manual I have come across by far. It gets dense sometimes, but the explanations are generally worth it in the end.

Comment: This works but only problem that i have is everything has to be in a single command which i need to remove date also. Because the contents inside CMD is read from a text file and that gets executed within the legacy code. Say if there are 20 parameters with comma seperated values, i have this CMD in 10th parameter which gets executed as CMD.

Comment: @Karthik. If you could post an example of exactly what you mean, I could help you with that. I am not sure I understand your explanation completely as it stands.

Comment: Here is my sample. I have a text file like this. 1,2,3,4,5,`echo prefix_filename.txt | sed 's/^prefix_//'`_`date +%m%d%Y`,7,8,9,10 and i cut 6th parameter and assign to my CMD parameter. since i cant change the code, i have have my 6th parameter itself handle the complete logic.

Comment: Can you replace the part that says `echo prefix_filename.txt | sed 's/^prefix_//'_date +%m%d%Y` with this: `ORIG=prefix_filename.txt; echo ${ORIG#prefix_}_$(date +%m%d%Y)`?

Comment: Also, I am assuming you are using the dreaded `eval` builtin for this?

Comment: No I am no using the eval. I need to have 'date in command with escape character (`) to satisfy legacy code. I have written like this. Can you help me in getting date removed now with the given command.    $((echo "$file_name".`date +%Y%m%d`| sed 's/^prefix_//')

Comment: There is a escape character before date(') but somehow it doesnt get posted

Answer (score 0):

Just do that:

```
echo filename.txt_09232016 | sed s/_[^_]*$//
```

Here, you are replacing (by nothing) ' _ ' and all subsequent characters, until the end of the string ($), since they are all different (^) of ' _ '.

Comment: But is it possible to have this change in the same command where CMD gets assigned instead of going to a new line and removing date timestamp again. Because the command is stored in a text file and script reads from them. Whatever is inside CMD= <> is read from a text file

Comment: If you happen to have an underscore in the real file name, you are screwed.

Comment: Yes real filename has lot of underscores :D